# Picture download overhead

Tags: cocoa-touch, image, memory, download, afnetworking

My app has an UITableView. Its cells downloads pictures from tumblr using AFNetworking. This actually does work but I noticed that my app need like 5 MB more of memory as soon as I start downloading pictures. I first though that it's a leak, however, my app doesn't have a leak. So I checked the memory usage of instagram and such and noticed that they need more memory too, as soon as I start downloading posts.

So I'm wondering why downloading images involves such a big overhead? Or am I totally wrong and my app's not working?

Answer (score 0):

That memory overhead is the data of the images being displayed in `UIImageView`s. `UIImage` decompresses the original encoding (JPEG, PNG, etc.) and rasterizes it into an internal bitmap representation that is easily drawn to the screen. This is why your memory overhead may seem large as compared to the size of the assets downloaded from the server.

That said, make sure to update AFNetworking to `HEAD` of master, as it includes a fix that reduces the memory footprint of the `UIImageView` category methods.